# Does every language that fulfills the regular Pumping conditions also fulfill the context-free ones?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

Let L be a language that fulfills the properties implies by the Pumping lemma for regular languages.
Does L necessarily fulfill the corresponding properties of the Pumping lemma for context-free languages as well?

Comment: Ok, if you didn't manage to contradict it, how about a proof that it is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is true. Try to provide some details in your question about how you approach the problem, and where you got stuck. This will make an answer much more productive.

Comment: What do you mean by "a language that fulfils the pumping lemma"? The pumping lemma is a fact about regular languages. It's not something that is fulfilled or not fulfilled by any particular language, just as, for example, Fermat's last theorem is neither fulfilled nor not fulfilled by any particular natural number.

Comment: @RickDecker "If $L$ is regular, then the PL applied to $L$ is true." No, the pumping lemma isn't "true for a language $L$": it's just true. It's a universal statement about languages, with no free variables: for all $L$, if $L$ is regular then $L$ has property $X$. For any specific language, one can look at the hypothesis and conclusion of that implication but is that "applying the pumping lemma to $L$"? When we use the pumping lemma to prove non-regularity, we use the contrapositive: for all languages $L$, if not $X$ then $L$ is not regular. What is "applying the PL to a language"?

Comment: Hint: look at the respective proofs.

Comment: @DavidRicherby. Let me try again. The PL says "If $L$ is a regular language, then the predicate $Q(L)$ is true", where $Q(L) $ is the familiar $\exists p > 0 \forall w\in L (|w|\ge p\Rightarrow\exists x, y, z (w=xyz \land |y|> 0\land |xy|\le p\dotsc$. So we have $L$ is regular $\Rightarrow Q(L)$ but the converse may not be true. I was suggesting that $Q$ might have been what the OP meant by "fulfills the properties implied by the PL".

Comment: @RickDecker Yes, that's a possibility. But the fact that the pumping lemma is almost always used in the contrapositive means that it could be the predicate $\neg Q(L)$ that's being referred to.

Comment: Please do not self-vandalize your post. This will not be tolerated. If you feel your question has been misunderstood, try to clarify it. You can ask the commenters if you don't understand their replies (using @-notification).

Answer (score 5):

Before giving the answers, some discussion on your direction for the proof:

It is highly unlikely that a proof of this claim would use the containment $REG\subseteq CFL$, since the pumping lemma is not an exact characterization, and if a language satisfies the regular pumping lemma, it doesn't proof that the language is regular.

Thus, the proof will have to go into the "guts" of the lemmas.
Now for the proof:

Consider a language $L$ that satisfies the regular pumping lemma. Thus, there exists some $p>0$ such that for every word $w\in L$, if $|w|>p$, then there exists a partition $w=xyz$ such that $|xy|\le p$, $|y|>0$ and for every $i$ it holds that $xy^iz\in L$.

We want to prove that there exists some $q>0$ such that for every word $w\in L$, if $|w|>q$, then there exists a partition $w=uvstr$ such that $|vst|\le q$, $|vt|>0$ and for every $i$ it holds that $uv^ist^ir\in L$.

Seeing things stated as above, the rest is just "pattern matching":
Let $q=p$, and consider a word $w\in L$ such that $|w|>q$, then there exists a partition $w=xyz$ as above. Let $u=x,v=y,s=\epsilon,t=\epsilon$, and $r=z$. Clearly $uvstr=xyz=w$. Also, $|xy|\le p$, so $|vst|=|y|\le p$ and $|y|>0$ so $|vt|=|v|=|y|>0$. Finally, for every $i$ it holds that 
$$uv^ist^ir=xy^iz\in L$$
and we are done.